# Ransack custom sorting not works

Tags: ruby, ransack, meta-search

I can't create custom sort for ransack(by scope). Tried to do as the tutorial says, but it not successful.

I have next code in my Model.

```
scope :sort_by_custom_name_asc, -> { order('"core_people"."phone" ASC') }
```

Proofs that scope works, sort by phone in ransack works, but custom_name sort don't.

```
Core::Person.ransack(s: 'custom_name asc').result.to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"core_people\".* FROM \"core_people\""

Core::Person.ransack(s: 'phone asc').result.to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"core_people\".* FROM \"core_people\" ORDER BYY\"core_people\".\"phone\" ASC"

Core::Person.sort_by_custom_name_asc.to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"core_people\".* FROM \"core_people\" ORDER BY \"core_people\".\"phone\" ASC"
```

Comment: What is `custom_name`? Is it a column in your database?

Comment: No it just piece scope

Comment: scope :sort_by_custom_name_asc, -> { order('"core_people"."phone" ASC') }

Comment: In tutorial says that is should be with sort_by_ prefix and _asc or _desc postfix.

Comment: Would you mind linking the tutorial? Is the official [wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki)?

Comment: Do you want to sort by phone or custom name? SQL generated correctly, you wrote `"core_people"."phone"` and looks like worked.
In case if you need sort by `custom_name` field then it will looks like 
`scope :sort_by_custom_name_asc, -> { order('core_people.custom_name ASC') }`

Comment: [Tutorial](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search#sorting-columns)
I want to sort by harder query with several fields, and it as scope for the model works. I started researching why i can't sort in ransack and found out that any my custom scope search not work. (custom_name isn't a field, it's only linking for sort example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do this.
Now the sort by custom_name available from ransack.

```
ransacker :custom_name do |_|
  Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('"core_people"."phone"')
end
```